# Graph a daily amount in between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

The source table has a table with a single amount and a revenue start and revenue end date. I need to graph the amount over the period by day in PowerBI.

For example:
[image]

Looking at the second row the total amount is 730 but I need to calculate a daily rate and display this each day for the revenue period. So if I had a bar chart for this row I would need to show it as 16 April  has 34.76, 17 April has 34.76 and so on until 6 May which is the revenue end date. I've tried using between dates but cant seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power BI's CALENDAR() function to create a table of dates ranging from the minimum revenue start date to the maximum revenue end date.

```
Dates = CALENDAR(MIN(BookFees[Revenue Start Date]),MAX(BookFees[Revenue End Date]))
```

Then you can create a calculated column in the Dates table for the daily revenue.

```
Daily Revenue = Calculate(SUM(BookFees[RevenueDayAmount]),FILTER(BookFees,BookFees[Revenue Start Date]<=Dates[Date] && BookFees[Revenue End Date]>= Dates[Date]))
```

Here is the resulting bar chart:

[image: result]

Comment: This will work for the above. An addition to the above is that there are lines for different students, which I didn't include in the original table. I think though that your suggestion could generalize by creating a table to unpivot